# How to use Mapbox Geocoding API in JavaScript to reverse geocode a point?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have read a lot of SO questions and answers and looked at [the Mapbox documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#reverse-geocoding) but I can't see a simple example of how to reverse geocode from a latitude/longitude point. [The example](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#example-request-reverse-geocoding) only shows the URL to use to make a query but presumably there's a way to do it using the `MapboxGeocoder` object?

So, here, what would I use to display the reverse geocode for lat/long when the user clicks on the map?

```js
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: document.getElementsByClassName("js-map")[0],
  center: [0, 51],
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
  zoom: 11
});

map.on("click", function(ev) {
  // 1. Reverse geocode `ev.lngLat.lat` and `ev.lngLat.lng`
  // 2. Do something with the result.
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [Mapbox SDK for JS](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js) which is a wrapper around the rest API.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/umd/mapbox-sdk.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var mapboxClient = mapboxSdk({ accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken });
mapboxClient.geocoding
  .reverseGeocode({
    query: "lng,lat"
  })
  .send()
  .then(function(response) {
    if (
      response &&
      response.body &&
      response.body.features &&
      response.body.features.length
    ) {
      var feature = response.body.features[0];
    }
  });
```

The MapboxGeocoder plugin for Mapbox GL JS is to provide an out of the box search box interface, not for calling the API directly.

Comment: Just keep in mind "If you are supporting older browsers, you will need a Promise polyfill. es6-promise is a good one, if you're uncertain."

Comment: const MapboxGeocoder = require('@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/services/geocoding');
const geocoder = MapboxGeocoder({ accessToken: MY_ACCESS_TOKEN });
geocoder.reverseGeocoder(...)

Answer (score 2):

Unless someone comes up with a better answer, here's what I've done.

To do this you *don't* need to include any of the Mapbox Geocoding CSS/JS, which I assume are only needed for displaying the widget that a user types into, and which can display a list of results:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.4.2/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css
https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.4.2/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.min.js
```

So, assuming we have a `<div class="js-map"></div>`, and have included the `mapbox-gl-js` CSS and JS files, here we use jQuery to do the geocoding request:

```js
var api_key = "YOUR-API-KEY";

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: document.getElementsByClassName("js-map")[0],
  center: [0, 51],
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
  zoom: 11
});

map.on("click", function(ev) {
  $.get(
    "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/" +
      ev.lngLat.lon + "," + ev.lngLat.lat + ".json?access_token=" + api_key,
    function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  ).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("There was an error while geocoding: " + errorThrown);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is correct, though I've provided an alternate answer using the Mapbox SDK for JS as a wrapper.

Comment: Thanks! We're both right but, while I've stuck with my solution, yours is probably more what I was originally looking for so I've marked it correct. It was frustrating there wasn't a link to a usable example in the reverse geocoding documentation.